# How to unit test without mocks and not be tied to a concrete implementations of an interface

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking

I consider myself to be a 'mockist' on the 'mockist' vs 'classicist' debate, but I am trying to understand the other point of view.

Imagine I have this class, where a concrete instance of `IDependency` is injected by an IoC container.

`IDependency` does not access a remote resource like a database or web service (in which case I would definately mock it), it is just another class containing some business logic.

```
public class UnitUnderTest
{
    public UnitUnderTest ( IDependency dependency )
    {
    }
}
```

Using this pattern, I am free to change the concrete implementation of `IDependency` by changing the class injected by the IoC container. I am not *tied* to any particular implementation.

If I was to test this class without mocking `IDependency`, wouldn't I have to instantiate my *real* `IDependency` to pass in to the constructor?

```
public class My_Unit_Test()
{
    IDependency concreteDependency = new ConcreteDependency();
    var unitUnderTest = new UnitUnderTest(concreteDependency);
}
```

In this example, if I write a replacement to `ConcreteDependency`, I would have to not only change my IoC container configuration, but all of my unit tests that use `ConcreteDependency`.

Or.. do I use the same IoC container within my unit tests (which seems like it goes against the idea of testing things in isolation)?

Comment: Isn't the distinction only relevant if `IDependency` were a concrete class, rather than merely an interface?

Comment: Please stop... DHH put together a strawman and attacked it brutally, but it was a strawman nonetheless.

His argument was directly that a lot of our techniques for abstracting dependencies away is a direct result of the requirements placed by unit testing. How can I test for a dependency I haven't made yet? I mock it and inject the dependency in the unit under test. For projects under 10 developers, this might be over kill. For large scale enterprise projects it could be the difference between success and failure

Comment: @MikeBrown I agree, which is why I posted this question. I am trying to understand the other side of the argument and how it works in practice.

Comment: Who is DHH? ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: David Heinemeier Hannson. http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/

Comment: ...and the location of the straw man?  If you guys are going to bring your argument here, you might as well let us in on it.

Comment: If only all large scale enterprise projects could have more than 10 developers. Mock things first because you never know when you might not need the real thing.

Comment: Sorry @RobertHarvey this belongs more in Meta. I'll provide links there. But I have a feeling a lot of TDD Pro/Con arguments will be surfacing on Programmers from that.

Comment: This is a good summary of the brewhaha http://kickstartacademy.io/blog/2014-05-02-to-tdd-or-not-to-tdd-that-is-not-the-question-

Comment: @MikeBrown: Thanks for the link.  It's essentially Uncle Bob's argument, but it begs the question, and always has.  After all, if I've owned a car, why would I ever use any other form of transportation?  And if I've never owned a car, how would I be qualified to say that other transportation is adequate, desirable, or maybe even preferable?  All those programmers who wrote code before TDD came along were obviously not professionals, and saying your not a professional if you don't use TDD is just another form of religion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I was to test this class without mocking IDependency, wouldn't I have to instantiate my real IDependency to pass in to the constructor?

No, you could create a fake `IDependency` for your specific needs. You may even make your "real" `IDependency` but parameterize it specifically to your needs. Though depending on who you talk to, these are considered mock objects since they're not used in production.

This is the common argument against mocking everything: you already have objects to do this stuff that are robust, flexible and trustworthy. You don't mock `IList` in your tests because `List` is a dependency do you?

Like most arguments, the best approach is often a balance of the two.

> In this example, if I write a replacement to ConcreteDependency, I would have to not only change my IoC container configuration, but all of my unit tests that use ConcreteDependency.

Yes, just like you'd have to change all of your mocks should you replace your mock objects.

> How to unit test without mocks and not be tied to a concrete implementations of an interface

**You literally can not.**

You need to create a concrete implementation of that interface ***somewhere***. You could share that instance between tests, but that is against best practice (tests are not isolated). You could have a factory to generate the object, but then you have added complexity and it's uncommon that a single type of instance can be used for every test. But in the end, the test needs a concrete implementation to work, no matter how much indirection you put between the test and the thing.

Comment: The difference as I see it is that if I use mocks, I can use a 'fakes' framework to create them from an interface and use those in the tests. If I use the real thing, I am tying my unit tests to those concrete implementations. Is this unavoidable? If so, it seems like using a 'fakes' framework like NSubstitute would be preferable as the tests are less coupled to the 'real' implementation.

Comment: @DaveS - sure, you can use something like Moq to create test objects from an interfaces, but there's still a concrete object your test depends on. The argument arises if it's quicker/easier/more robust to do that versus make your own test object by hand or use an existing object.

Comment: Agreed. That has clarified it for me (although I think I will have to try it before having a real opinion).

Answer (score 4):

*You only need an IoC container if you want to centralize your dependency declarations.*  For everything else, there's ordinary constructor injection.

To put it another way, *you don't need an IoC container in your unit tests.*  You're not testing the IoC container, after all.

To put it still another way, if you're stitching together a bunch of mock dependencies in your unit tests using an IoC container, they're no longer unit tests; they're integration tests (*mock* integration tests, if there is such a thing).

Comment: This was my point, I shouldn't be using an IoC container. This means that I have to hard code all of my concrete implementations in to my unit tests.

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: Only in that if change the class that I use as the concrete implementation in my real application, I need to modify all of my unit tests. If I mock them, I only need to change the mocks if the interface changes.

Comment: @DaveS: If you're using an IoC container, you're not really testing a unit, you're testing a bunch of units.

Comment: @DougM This is exactly my question, I cannot use an IoC container, so I am forced to hard-code my concrete classes.

Comment: You don't need an IoC container to mock them, so I don't understand your statement about modifications.  If you change the implementation in your real application (say, for performance reasons), but the contracted behavior stays the same, then your tests will not change, IoC container or not.  I assume that, if you *do* use an IoC container in your tests, you will be configuring the container with mock objects, not the real ones.

Comment: @RobertHarvey To clarify, the question was how to test using real objects instead of mocks. Normally I use mocks (and no IoC container in unit tests!)